# Adding up file sizes in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of many files and their sizes. Unfortunately, the sizes are given in KB, MB or GB.
So it is not possible to simply add the individual sizes, since it recognizes the cells as text cells. 
Anybody have any idea how I could add up all the values?
Thanks for all your help!
[Excel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6SmN.png)

Comment: Does it need to handle file sizes in bytes, or just KB
MB
GB
TB
PB
EB
ZB
YB? Also, do you want the answer in bytes or KB?

Comment: No, just up from KB. The Answer should be in TB, if that is possible. I first thought of formatting the cells with a custom filesize-format but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this formula on C1 and pull down, then you can sum:

```
=VALUE(LEFT(B1,LEN(B1)-2))*(IF(RIGHT(B1,2)="KB",1,IF(RIGHT(B1,2)="MB",1024,IF(RIGHT(B1,2)="GB",1024*1024))))
```

Comment: Thanks, that should do it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the idea. You can tinker with format and such. Let us assume you have everything with number, a space, and a unit afterwards of the form KB
MB
GB
TB
PB
EB
ZB
YB. Then off to the side (could be hidden later if you wish, I used F1:F8, place one under the other KB,MB, GB, TB, PB, EB, ZB, and YB. In the cell next to KB, write `=2^10`. In the cell beneath that, write `=2^10*G1` (or equivalent), and drag this formula all the way down to the cell next to YB. You now have a table to convert to bytes.

Now suppose your file sizes are in column B. In column C, we strip off just the number as, `=left(B1,len(B1)-3)` (this too can be dragged down as far as needed), and in column D we grab just the value of the unit corresponding to the 2 letters with: `=vlookup(right(B1,2),$F$1:$G$8,2,FALSE)`, and this too gets dragged down as far as needed. Column E gets `=C1*D1` and so on down, which can be summed (for example `=sum(E1:E3)`) to get an answer in bytes, which you may convert to other units and format as you see fit.

EDIT: I see now you want the answer in TB. Assuming TB are in line 4,columns F and G, you adapt your sum as `=sum(E1:E3)/$G$4 &" "& $F$4`